# Values in array are changing when exiting

Tags: c++

So I'm trying to implement breadth first search for determining the shortest path in a bipartite graph for a project. The problem I am having is that the values of my initial arrays are changing from the "bfs" function to the "printShortestPath" function as can be seen at the end. What would be causing the array values to randomly change?

Header:

```
#define BGRAPH_H

using namespace std;

#include <vector>
#include <list>

class bgraph {
    public:
        bgraph(int numV);
        void addEdge(int v1, int v2);
        bool bfs(int v1, int v2);
        void printShortestPath(int v1, int v2);
        void removeDuplicates();
    private:
        int numVertex;
        vector<vector<int>> adjacencyLists;
        bool visited[];
        int pred[];
        int dist[];
};

#endif
```

Cpp

```
using namespace std;

#include "bgraph.h"
#include <list>
#include <set>

#include <iostream> // TEST

bgraph::bgraph(int numV) {
    numVertex = numV;
    adjacencyLists.resize(numV);
    bool visited[numV] = {false};
    int pred[numV];
    int dist[numV];

    cout << "got to constructor\n";

    for (int i = 0; i < numVertex; i++) {
        pred[i] = -1;
        dist[i] = 1000;
    }

    cout << "pred:\n";
    for (int i = 0; i < numVertex; i++)
        cout << pred[i] << " ";
    cout << endl << endl;
    cout << "dist:\n";
    for (int i = 0; i < numVertex; i++)
        cout << dist[i] << " ";
    cout << endl << endl;
    cout << "visited:\n";
    for (int i = 0; i < numVertex; i++)
        cout << visited[i] << " ";
    cout << endl << endl;
}


void bgraph::addEdge(int v1, int v2) {
    adjacencyLists.at(v1).push_back(v2);
    adjacencyLists.at(v2).push_back(v1);
}

bool bgraph::bfs(int v1, int v2) {
    list<int> queue;
    visited[v1] = true;
    dist[v1] = 0;
    queue.push_back(v1);

    // Look at values of pred, dist, and visisted
    cout << "pred:\n";
    for (int i = 0; i < numVertex; i++)
        cout << pred[i] << " ";
    cout << endl << endl;
    cout << "dist:\n";
    for (int i = 0; i < numVertex; i++)
        cout << dist[i] << " ";
    cout << endl << endl;
    cout << "visited:\n";
    for (int i = 0; i < numVertex; i++)
        cout << visited[i] << " ";
    cout << endl << endl;

    while (!queue.empty()) {
        int currentVertex = queue.front();
        queue.pop_front();
        for (int i = 0; i < adjacencyLists.at(currentVertex).size(); i++) {
            int nextVertex = adjacencyLists.at(currentVertex).at(i);
            if (!visited[nextVertex]) {
                //cout << "Next vertex: " << nextVertex << endl; // TEST
                visited[nextVertex] = true;
                dist[nextVertex] = dist[currentVertex] + 1;
                //cout << "dist[nextVertex]: " << dist[nextVertex] << endl; // TEST
                pred[nextVertex] = currentVertex;
                //cout << "pred[nextVertex]: " << pred[nextVertex] << endl; // TEST
                queue.push_back(nextVertex);
                if (nextVertex == v2) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}

void bgraph::printShortestPath(int v1, int v2) {
    if (!bfs(v1, v2)) {
        cout << "No connection.\n";
        return;
    }
    vector<int> shortestPath;
    int iter = v2;
    shortestPath.push_back(iter);
    while (pred[iter] != -1) {
        shortestPath.push_back(pred[iter]);
        iter = pred[iter];
    }
    cout << "Path is: \n";
    for (int i = shortestPath.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        cout << shortestPath.at(i) << " ";
    cout << endl;
}

void bgraph::removeDuplicates() {
    set<int> noDuplicates;
    for (int i = 0; i < adjacencyLists.size(); i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < adjacencyLists.at(i).size(); j++)
            noDuplicates.insert(adjacencyLists.at(i).at(j));
        adjacencyLists.at(i).clear();
        if (noDuplicates.find(i) != noDuplicates.end())
            noDuplicates.erase(i);
        set<int>::iterator iter = noDuplicates.begin();
        while (iter != noDuplicates.end()) {
            adjacencyLists.at(i).push_back(*iter);
            iter++;
        }
        noDuplicates.clear();
    }
}
```

Output in constructor:

```
pred:
-1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1

dist:
1000 1000 1000 1000 1000 1000 1000 1000 1000 1000 1000 1000 1000 1000 1000 1000 1000 1000 1000 1000 1000 1000 1000 1000 1000 1000 1000 1000 1000 1000 1000 1000 1000 1000 1000 1000 1000 1000 1000 1000 1000 1000 1000 1000 1000 1000 1000 1000 1000 1000 1000 1000 1000 1000 1000 1000 1000 1000 1000 1000 1000 1000 1000 1000 1000 1000 1000 1000 1000 1000 1000 1000 1000 1000 1000 1000 1000 1000 1000 1000 1000 1000 1000 1000 1000 1000 1000 1000 1000 1000 1000 1000 1000 1000 1000 1000 1000 1000 1000 1000

visited:
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

Output of same arrays when they're being called in bfs function:

```
pred:
12124608 0 0 0 12131016 32566 -1417405256 32764 -1417405245 32764 -1417405245 32764 0 0 0 0 0 0 12158624 32566 8 0 -1417405256 32764 11 0 1634493778 824206708 3487008 0 12131304 32566 6 0 0 0 4098 0 6 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 8 0 -1417405176 32764 12158624 32566 0 0 0 0 -1417405344 32764 12157120 32566 12157008 32566 12157024 32566 0 0 0 1

dist:
12124608 0 0 0 12131016 32566 -1417405256 32764 -1417405245 32764 -1417405245 32764 0 0 0 0 0 0 12158624 32566 8 0 -1417405256 32764 11 0 1634493778 824206708 3487008 0 12131304 32566 6 0 0 0 4098 0 6 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 8 0 -1417405176 32764 12158624 32566 0 0 0 0 -1417405344 32764 12157120 32566 12157008 32566 12157024 32566 0 0 0 1

visited:
192 1 185 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 200 26 185 0 54 127 0 0 184 28 132 171 252 127 0 0 195 28 132 171 252 127 0 0 195 28 132 171 252 127 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 160 134 185 0 54 127 0 0 8 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 184 28 132 171 252 127 0 0 11 0 0 0
```

Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: `bool visited[];int pred[];int dist[];` and this: `bool visited[numV] = {false}; int pred[numV]; int dist[numV];` -- This is not valid C++.  Arrays in C++ require their sizes denoted by a compile-time constant, not a runtime value.  Use `std::vector<bool> visited(numV);` and `std::vector<int> pred(numV), dist(numV);` instead.  Also, you are already using `vector`, so why didn't you notice that you should have used it there also?

Comment: The `visited`, `pred`, and `dist` arrays declared in your constructor body are local variables, and not the members declared in the class. The zero length arrays declared in your class are non-standard.  You should use `vector` for them.

Comment: I bet if they were `vector` instead of the fake syntax, the bug would have been more noticeable to the OP.

Comment: Wow, thank you guys for pointing that out. I've been going at this all day and am losing it a little bit. I've changed them all to vectors and it works perfect now.